# Allocate space for optional flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to design a menu item list which has four options, three of which are always present:

- Item
- Price
- topping `//optional`
- Order button

I cant figure out how to always ensure that the **Order** button is fixed to the end of the list so space is allocated for the missing option

```css
.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: space-between;
}
.menu-item #menu-item-form {
  display: none;
}
.menu-item .item {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.menu-item .fill {
  flex-basis: 10%;
}
.menu-item button{

  flex-basis: 20%;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<li class="menu-item">
  <form id="menu-item-form">
  </form>
  <div class="item">Chicken Burger</div>
  <span class="fill price">1350.00</span>
  <button class="order-btn" form="menu-item-form" type="submit">Add to Order</button>
</li>
```

Comment: read the second answer of the duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif i'm not 100% sure that answers OPs question - even the second answer

Comment: `how to always ensure that Order button is fixed to the end of the list so space is allocated` --> he want the button to be aligned to the right and he used align-self which is the wrong property because it will align on the cross axis not the main axis. All he need is to use margin auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor update to your code `justify-content: space-between;` fixes the issue :)

```css
.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.menu-item #menu-item-form {
  display: none;
}
.menu-item .item {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.menu-item .fill {
  flex-basis: 10%;
}
.menu-item button{
  flex-basis: 20%;
}
```

```html
<li class="menu-item">
  <div class="item">Chicken Burger</div>
  <span class="fill price">1350.00</span>
  <button class="order-btn" form="menu-item-form" type="submit">Add to Order</button>
</li>
```